# More natural way of Proc calling in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

As we know, there are several way of Proc calling in Ruby 1.9

```
 f =->n {[:hello, n]}
 p f[:ruby]       # => [:hello, :ruby]
 p f.call(:ruby)  # => [:hello, :ruby]
 p f.(:ruby)      # => [:hello, :ruby]
 p f === :ruby    # => [:hello, :ruby]
```

I am curious, what is more 'natural' way of calling Proc? 'Natural', probably, means more Computer Science - like way.

Comment: I'd go for option 2. It seems natural. The rest looks bizarre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second option is by far the most used.

```
p f.call(:ruby)  # => [:hello, :ruby]
```

It makes it more similar to a standard method. Also, some libraries actually rely on duck typing when validating arguments checking the availability of the `#call` method. In this case, using `#call` ensures you can provide a lambda or any other object (including a Class) that responds to `#call`.

`Rack` middlewares are a great example of this convention. The basic middleware can be a lambda, or you can supply more complex logic by using classes.

Comment: +1 for the duck typing part -- that's important. In a lot of my own code, I use `.responds_to(:call)` so that people can pass a `Method`, a `Proc` or a lambda (or anything else with a `call` method).

Comment: Yes, fixed. I counted the first line. :P

Comment: All of this applies to `f.(:ruby)` as well, since that's just syntactic sugar for `f.call(:ruby)`.

Answer (score 1):

I always use option 3. Considering the syntactic ambiguities of being able to call methods without parentheses, this is the closest you can get to actual method call syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the first way used in **Rack** source code. It confused me in a long time. It's picked from **lib/rack/builder.rb** (**version: 1.6.0.alpha**)

```
module Rack
  class Builder
    ...

    def to_app
      app = @map ? generate_map(@run, @map) : @run
      fail "missing run or map statement" unless app

      # This is the first option calling a proc
      # @use is a array of procs (rack middleware)
      @use.reverse.inject(app) { |a,e| e[a] }
    end

    ...
  end
end
```